# In Enzyme, how do you allow a function available on the window, to de defined on a variable declared in the constructor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, sinon, event-listener

**GoogleMarker Component:**

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ChildComponent from "./info-window";

export default class Marker extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      markerCreated: false
    };

    this.marker = null;
    this._init = this._init.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._init();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { position } = this.props;
    if (
      position.lat !== nextProps.position.lat ||
      position.lng !== nextProps.position.lng
    ) {
      this.marker.setPosition(nextProps.position);
    }
  }

  _init() {
    const { icon, position, map, title, club } = this.props;
    this.marker = new this.props.googleApi.Marker({
      icon,
      position,
      map,
      title
    });
    this.marker.addListener("click", () => {
      if (this.props.onSelect) {
        this.props.onSelect(club, true);
      }
    });
    this.setState({ markerCreated: true });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.marker) {
      this.marker.setMap(null);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      this.state.markerCreated && (
        <ChildComponent
          googleApi={this.props.googleApi}
          map={this.props.map}
          mapRef={this.props.mapRef}
          marker={this.marker}
          show={this.props.showInfoWindow}
          onSelect={this.props.onSelect}
          onDeselect={this.props.onDeselect}
        />
      )
    );
  }
}

Marker.displayName = "Marker";
Marker.propTypes = {
  googleApi: PropTypes.object,
  map: PropTypes.object,
  mapRef: PropTypes.object,
  position: PropTypes.shape({
    lat: PropTypes.number,
    lng: PropTypes.number
  }),
  title: PropTypes.string,
  club: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.bool, PropTypes.object]),
  showInfoWindow: PropTypes.bool,
  onSelect: PropTypes.func,
  onDeselect: PropTypes.func
};
```

**GoogleMarker Test:**

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Marker from "src/components/marker";

describe("components/marker", () => {
  let props;
  let component;
  const addListenerSpy = sinon.spy();
  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      googleApi: {
        Marker: sinon.spy(),
      },
      map: {},
      position: {
        lat: 10,
        lng: 10
      },
      title: "title",
      club: { id: 1, name: "NAME", state: "CA" },
      showInfoWindow: false,
      onSelect: sinon.spy()
    };
    component = shallow(<Marker {...props} />);

    it("should render into the document", () => {
      expect(component).to.not.be.null;
    });
  });
```

Test fails on `mount` on call to `_init` with the **error**:

```
this.marker.addListener is not a function
```

**In the Enzyme test for the component at hand, how do you allow a function available on the window, to de defined on a variable declared in the constructor?**

Comment: Did you meant using `this.variable.addListener` instead of `this.marker.addListener` in this code example? If not, where is `this.marker` declared?

Comment: Were you the downvote - when you knew the answer? Yes - that was supposed to be variable - trying to keep it generic. I've updated the question, and I also believe addListener may live on the window - so mocking that could be the solution.

Comment: Nope, I didn't downvote your question.

Comment: The question doesn't contain the actual code, so it's unclear what went wrong. *something like this line* - it would result in syntax error, try it. You won't have problems if it really returns an object with addListener method. Try to check yourself by writing an assertion that it's really so. I didn't downvote but the problem seems that you can't debug the code you wrote. Also, noop functions are bad idea, use stubs. Also, using globals is very bad idea.

Comment: All the relevant code is above - the unnecessary parts are left out. 
The core problem is simple - and if I knew the syntax I wouldn't need to ask the answer.
If the object returned addListener - I wouldn't have asked the question. 
Also, spies, and stubs are not relevant here. 
Being able to access addListener on the global variable is what's relevant. 
Not sure if you're familiar with react, but declaring variables in the constructor is a common practice.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution**:

**First attempt (incorrect):**

In the test, I ended up trying something like this, which was incorrect:

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Marker from "src/components/marker";

describe("components/marker", () => {
  let props;
  let component;
  const addListenerSpy = sinon.spy();
  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      googleApi: {
        Marker: () => {
          // incorrect
          this.addListener = sinon.spy();
        },
      },
      map: {},
      position: {
        lat: 10,
        lng: 10
      },
      title: "title",
      club: { id: 1, name: "NAME", state: "CA" },
      showInfoWindow: false,
      onSelect: sinon.spy()
    };
    component = shallow(<Marker {...props} />);

    it("should render into the document", () => {
      expect(component).to.not.be.null;
    });
});
```

**Second attempt (correct)**:

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow, mount } from "enzyme";
import Marker from "src/components/marker";

describe("components/marker", () => {
  let props;
  let component;
  const addListenerSpy = sinon.spy();
  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      googleApi: {
        // Here the spy is added as an object wrapped in parens
        Marker: () => ({ addListener: addListenerSpy }),
      },
      map: {},
      position: {
        lat: 10,
        lng: 10
      },
      title: "St. Petersburg Sam's Club",
      club: { id: 1, name: "NAME", state: "FL" },
      showInfoWindow: false,
      content: "<div></div>",
      onSelect: sinon.spy()
    };
    component = shallow(<Marker {...props} />);

    it("should render into the document", () => {
      expect(component).to.not.be.null;
    });
});
```